# The problem of different result values ​due to capturing in Kotlin sequence

Tags: kotlin

If a value called prime is declared externally in the problem code, Capturing occurs, resulting in different results. Can someone tell me in detail why the result value is different when capturing occurs?

**normal code**

```
val primes: Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    var numbers = generateSequence(2) { it + 1 }

    while (true) {
        val prime = numbers.first()
        yield(prime)
        numbers = numbers.drop(1)
            .filter {
                it % prime != 0
            }
    }
}
println(primes.take(10).toList()) // [2, 3, 5, 7. 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

**problem code**

```
val primes: Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    var numbers = generateSequence(2) { it + 1 }
    var prime: Int
    while (true) {
        prime = numbers.first()
        yield(prime)
        numbers = numbers.drop(1)
            .filter {
                it % prime != 0
            }
    }
}
println(primes.take(10).toList()) // [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Lambda capture occurs when using sequences

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method `filter { it % prime != 0 }` you permanently attach one filter, with its lambda function, to the `numbers` Sequence object. The value of `prime` in that lambda is captured from the enclosing code. With each loop, more and more filters are attached to the `numbers` Sequence.

In the first (working) example, each time a filter lambda is attached to the `numbers` Sequence, it gets its own unique version of the `prime` variable. Specifically, it gets the unique `val prime` that is defined at the start of the `while` loop in which that filter lambda is attached. That's just what you want.

In the second (broken) example, there is only one `prime` variable throughout the program: the `var prime` defined outside the loop. It changes every time the `while` loop runs. That means that every filter lambda is identical at any point in time: they all use the same `prime` value, being the last number taken off the front of the (chopped) `numbers` sequence. And `prime` keeps going up by one with each iteration. All in all, it means with each loop all the identical filter lambda functions also change and so have no discernible effect on the `numbers` sequence, or in turn the sequence printed to the screen.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have two questions.
1. When yield is executed, is it correct to return a value and then drop and filter? 
and why do I drop and filter multiple times when importing a single sequence?

2.The prime value increases by 1, but can you tell me why 4 is excluded?

Comment: 1a) There are many ways to write out the prime numbers, and the "drop and filter" works, so go with it :) You can optimise later if you need to. 1b) Every time a number in the output sequence is generated, it comes from an iteration of the while loop (the "yield"). Immediately afterwards another filter is added, ready for generation of the next number from the next "yield". 2) 4 is excluded in the third iteration of the while loop because the first filter added filters out multiples of 2 from "numbers". And same for every subsequent number "yielded".

Comment: No problem. If you could upvote and accept useful answers, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `filter` method is evaluated lazily, every iteration of the loop again and again. In the first code block, you define `prime` locally so that's what's captured. In the second block, it knows `prime` is reassigned every time, so it'll only look at the latest value.

Comment: thank you
1st run drop & filter
2st run drop&filter twice work like this? 
I don't quite understand why every iteration of the loop repeats due to lazy evaluation.